# Setting MS references via gyp

Tags: node.js, dll, node-gyp, gyp

I need to compile something with gyp. I make use of some windows APIs, so I need to add the following lines to my vcxproj-file

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

How do I add these lines with gyp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another way and referenced the libraries via a `#using "filenanme"` directive in the source file.